# How to fit two inline elements to the body width?

Tags: html, css, inline

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Title</title>
<style type="text/css">

#container {
    position: relative;
}
#line {
    border-bottom: thin solid gray;
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    bottom: 1ex;
    width:90%;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <span id="title">Title</span>
    <span id="line"></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do i make that the width of span "line" to be equal with
the width of "container" minus width of the span "title"?

**Edit**

The width of the "title" to be decided by the text inside the "title".

Comment: It would be more readable to ask your question above or below of your code desert.

Comment: You are right. I was not sure how stackoverflow works and i got some weird display, maybe because I am using firefox 3.6b1.

Answer (score 1):

The easy answer is to give #title a width.  For example, if you assign #title a width of 10%, than your problem is over (as you've already assigned #line a width of 90%).  The not so easy answer is to use JavaScript to calculate the widths.

Comment: What about if i use for "title" width=50px ? Isn't there a trick with css that will make "line" to fill the rest of the empty space?